# asynchronous operations result in insonsistent results

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, callback

I'm new to nodejs and struggling with its asynchronous behaviour. 
What I want to do is writing an REST API, which will consumes other APIs and is dependent on these results. 
What I tried to do is capsuling the calls into functions [1] and collect the data and do something with it [2] before I send it to the caller of my API.
The problem is that at the time I'm collecting [2] the data, the `callApiX` functions [1] are still running which will end up in `undefined` values. Also, I need to call some of the functions more than 1 time and compare the values.

[1] Functions to call APIs:

```
function callApi1() {
    var result =
    {
        "code": "",
        "name": "",
        "lat": 0,
        "lng": 0
    };
    var request = require("request");
    var url = "someurl";
    request({
        url: url,
        json: true
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {

            // fill result
            result.code = body.code; // etc.

            // the correct result is being displayed
            console.log(result);

            return result;
        }
    })
}

function callApi2() // ...
```

[2] get Data from functions and add to request

```
var express    = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

app.route('/api')
.get(function(req, res) {

    // array for results
    var results = [];

    // all this data is going to be undefined, since the callApiX functions [1] are still running
    results += callApi1();
    results += callApi2();
    results += callApi3();

    // do something with the data collected in results before being sent back to the caller of my API

    res.json(results); // output: {undefinedundefinedundefined}

});
```

How could I possibly solve this?

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.  Instead, use promises.

Comment: which implementation would you suggest me to use?

Comment: I like [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q).

Comment: I prefer async, I've added example with this library... Q is also good..

Comment: @Alexander what's your reason to prefer async over Q? I just wonder about the differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways (nested callbacks, promises ... ) how you can achieve what you want, one of them you can see below

Example how you can solve this problem with use [async](https://github.com/caolan/async),

```
npm install async
```

JS:

```
var async = require('async');    

function callApi1 (callback) {
    var result =
    {
        "code": "",
        "name": "",
        "lat": 0,
        "lng": 0
    };
    var request = require("request");
    var url     = "someurl";

    request({
        url: url,
        json: true
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
            result.code = body.code;
            return callback(null, result)
        } else {
            callback(error);
        }
    })
}

function callApi2() // ...


var express    = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

app.route('/api')
.get(function(req, res) {

    async.parallel([
        function(callback){
            callApi1(callback);
        },
        function(callback) {
            callApi2(callback);
        },
        function(callback){
            callApi3(callback);
        }
    ], function (err, results) {
        res.json(results);
    });

});
```

What function parallel do, from doc

> Run the tasks array of functions in parallel, without waiting until
>   the previous function has completed. If any of the functions pass an
>   error to its callback, the main callback is immediately called with
>   the value of the error. Once the tasks have completed, the results are
>   passed to the final callback as an array.